# Laravel validation does not work for mime type otf font

Tags: laravel-5

I have to validate otf and ttf font file when uploading ttf working fine but otf not pass the validation using laravel. below given the code sample that fail when i am trying to upload otf file

```
$validator = Validator::make(Request::file('file'), [
     $key => [
       'mimes:ttf,application/x-font-otf',
     ],
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
     return $this->getResponse(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $validator->errors()->all()[0]);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem here. Were you able to solve the issue?